# Old text in one color, new text in another color. Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Each day there is a new worksheet where I write some notes. I would like to have a button that creates a new worksheet everyday, puts the old text in black and when I start writing new text (can be in a cell with text already) it should be blue.
Is there a way to do that? I can use VBA as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run it, the cells with values on the activesheet will be blue and on the empty cells you will be writing in black:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Font.Color = vbBlue

End Sub
```